# Show ribbon banner on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

Is there any way to display an image when the user has scrolled, say 100 pixels down on your webpage? We'd like something similar to the 'request a quote ribbon' here http://cortezvisual.com/ and we want that image to show up only when the user has scrolled a little bit down the page, is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/tCz3w/

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
var Wposition = window.pageYOffset
var Dposition = document.getElementById('red').offsetTop;
var diff=Dposition-Wposition;
if(diff<=45)
{
document.getElementById('img').style.display="inline-block";
}
if(diff>45)
{
document.getElementById('img').style.display="none";
}    
}
```